# Trying to replicate a serial protocol

Tags: serial-communication, protocol, usb

Spent the last few weeks reading, typing, testing, rinse & repeat to no avail in solving a problem.

**Problem:** Trying to reverse engineer a serial protocol at work.  Instrument is currently being sold.  Speaks exclusively to a GUI that was 'written' in Labview and is old and buggy.  I can't navigate the Labview 'code' for the life of me and the old SW engineer is gone.  I have the firmware code - but I'm not a firmware guy and I can't seem to find any kind of communications protocol in the firmware (I'm looking for read functions in the UART routines with input compare logic.. can't find anything).

I've been using Busdog and some other serial monitors to read USB port communications between GUI and instrument.  I try to mimic what the GUI is saying, but I get different responses from instrument.  I've tried every common baud rate and I can't get the instrument to respond in the same manner (I'm seeing 57600 in firmware and software code but still can't get that baud rate to work).  Language I'm using is C# if that matters. Instrument also uses USB adapter for old style D-Sub serial cable, really not sure if that matters either.

**Here's the GUI/Instrument startup log**:

> > **Id    Type    Time    Length  Hex Ascii**
> >     12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.000000    4   00 00 00 00 ....
> >     12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.008934    4   00 00 00 00 ....
> >     12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.010073    4   00 00 00 00 ....
> >     12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.007099    4   00 00 00 00 ....
> >     12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.010093    4   00 00 00 00 ....
> >     12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.009898    4   00 00 00 00 ....
> >     12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.010076    4   00 00 00 00 ....
> >     12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.010085    4   00 00 00 00 ....
> >     12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.010055    4   00 00 00 00 ....
> >     12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.009993    4   00 00 00 00 ....
> >     12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.010076    4   00 00 00 00 ....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.478304    19  01 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ..................
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.015842    29  01 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00    ............................
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.035298    5   09 01 00 00 f6  .....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   1.476104    7   01 60 09 01 00 00 f6    ......
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.000255    4   01 00 00 ff ....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.255325    14  01 60 01 13 32 33 30 30 34 35
>   37 00 02 14   ...2300457...
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.016031    13  01 60 01 c7 00 78 00 58 f9 01
>   03 04 d8  ....x.X.....
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.001046    5   05 01 01 00 f9  .....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.190664    50  01 60 05 3c 01 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 43 44 4f 4d 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 52
>   46    ..<...................CDOM.....................RF
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.016036    18  01 60 55 00 00 00 00 00 4e 00
>   00 00 00 00 02 9d 03 bc   .U.....N.........
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.000203    5   05 01 02 00 f8  .....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.223419    9   01 60 05 3c 02 00 00 00
>   00    ..<.....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   1.015965    59  01 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 01 00 01 42 72 69 67 68 74 65 6e 65 72 73 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 52 46 55 00 00 00 00 00 4e 00 00 00 00 00 05
>   3f 06 b9  ...............Brighteners..............RFU.....N......?..
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.000705    5   05 01 03 00 f7  .....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.223026    7   01 60 05 3c 03 00 00    ..<...
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.015999    61  01 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 54 72 79 70 74 6f 70 68 61 6e 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 52 46 55 00 00 00 00 00 4e 00 00 00 00
>   00 05 82 06
>   b9    .................Tryptophan...............RFU.....N.........
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.000924    5   05 01 04 00 f6  .....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.238712    5   01 60 05 3c 04  ..<.
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.016021    63  01 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 43 34 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 52 46 55 00 00 00 00 00 4e 00 00
>   00 00 00 01 47 02
>   bd    ...................C4.......................RFU.....N......G..
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.000253    5   05 01 05 00 f5  .....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.239318    10  01 60 05 3c 05 00 00 00 00
>   00    ..<......
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.016044    58  01 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 01 00 01 43 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 52 46 55 00 00 00 00 00 4e 00 00 00 00 00 01 45
>   02 bd .`.............C5.......................RFU.....N......E..
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.000724    5   05 01 06 00 f4  .....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.239014    7   01 60 05 3c 06 00 00    ..<...
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   1.016014    61  01 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 43 36 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 52 46 55 00 00 00 00 00 4e 00 00 00 00
>   00 01 43 02
>   bd    .................C6.......................RFU.....N......C..
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.000268    5   05 01 07 00 f3  .....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.255336    55  01 60 05 3c 07 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 44 65 70 74 68 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 b0 43 00 00 00 00
>   00    ..<...................Depth.....................C.....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.015864    13  01 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
>   0f 03 bc  ............
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.009433    4   00 00 00 00 ....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.013163    6   01 60 00 00 00 00   .....
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.011897    4   00 00 00 00 ....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.010717    6   01 60 00 00 00 00   .....
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.011300    4   00 00 00 00 ....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.011293    6   01 60 00 00 00 00   .....
>   (idling at this point... )

**Here's my program/instrument log @ 57600 baud:**

> > **Id Type    Time    Length  Hex Ascii**
> >
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.000000    4   00 00 00 00 ....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.001779    7   01 68 30 00 ce 00 30    .h0...0
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.027282    70  01 60 e0 e7 3e fe 3e c0 fe 07
>   80 30 f8 98 fe 3e 0e f8 07 83 ce 06 0e f0 0e 00 30 1e ce e6 78 83 f0
>   0e fe 18 80 30 e0 30 00 30 3e 06 f8 30 00 30 1e 98 0e 1e e7 f0 18 3e
>   e0 98 00 f0 30 e0 ce 00 01 60 30 00 f0
>   f0    ...>.>....0...>..........0...x......0.0.0>..0.0.......>....0....0...
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  2.699018    4   00 00 00 00 ....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000785    3   01 70 00
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.001493    8   01 68 ce 00 30 00 f0 30
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.015390    9   01 60 e0 ce 00 30 00 f0 f0
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.669796    4   00 00 00 00
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000797    3   01 70 00
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.001374    8   01 68 ce 00 30 00 f0 30
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.016017    9   01 60 e0 ce 00 30 00 f0 f0
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.573729    4   00 00 00 00
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000870    3   01 70 00
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.001373    8   01 68 ce 00 30 00 f0 30
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.015141    9   01 60 e0 ce 00 30 00 f0 f0
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  2.286973    5   09 01 00 00 f6
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000881    3   01 68 c0
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000244    3   01 60 00
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.001108    8   01 68 33 00 30 00 f0 30
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.015015    10  01 60 00 fe e6 00 30 00 f0 f0
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.950696    4   01 00 00
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000805    3   01 68 c0
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000213    3   01 60 00
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.015034    8   01 60 33 00 30 00 f0 f0
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  0.561288    5   05 01 01 00 f9
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000797    3   01 68 f0
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000245    3   01 70 00
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.001254    8   01 68 33 00 30 00 f0 30
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000123    3   01 70 00
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000248    3   01 68 ff
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.015170    8   01 60 c6 00 30 00 f0 f0
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  1.869307    5   05 01 01 00 f9
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000888    3   01 68 f0
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000250    3   01 60 00
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.001117    8   01 68 33 00 30 00 f0
>   30    .h3.0..0
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000124    3   01 70 00    .p.
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000249    3   01 68 ff    .h.
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.015890    8   01 60 c6 00 30 00 f0
>   f0    ...0...
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  3.052994    5   05 01 02 00 f8  .....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000804    3   01 68 f0    .h.
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000124    3   01 70 00    .p.
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.001377    8   01 68 33 00 30 00 f0
>   30    .h3.0..0
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000123    3   01 60 00    ..
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000125    3   01 68 ff    .h.
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.015154    8   01 60 c6 00 30 00 f0
>   f0    ...0...
>
> > 12   Out  (USB URB Function: 9)  2.182100    5   05 01 03 00 f7  .....
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000870    3   01 68 f0    .h.
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.000207    3   01 60 00    ..
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.001265    8   01 68 33 00 30 00 f0
>   30    .h3.0..0
>
> 12    In  (USB URB Function: 9)   0.015650    10  01 60 00 fe e6 00 30 00 f0
>   f0    .....0...
>   >

Not sure why I can't match the startup routine.  Or match anything else.  I assume I'm missing something big.. I just don't know what.  Any insight helps.  Thanks.